# What is the best way to use connection request used in local server and hosting server

Tags: rest, codenameone

I have a problem with connection request when connecting to the Hosting by Restful service,but when trying to connect with local server the response code is 411 but on live with Hosting is return 200 here is my Code below, All configuration in the local server the same in the Hosting Server.

```
ConnectionRequest connectionrequest = new ConnectionRequest();
connectionrequest.setUrl(LinkServerID);         
connectionrequest.setTimeout(5000);         
connectionrequest.setFailSilently(true);         
NetworkManager.getInstance().addToQueueAndWait(connectionrequest);         
//Progress d = new Progress("Please wait...",connectionrequest,true);                  
if(connectionrequest.getResponseCode() != 0 && 
     connectionrequest.getResponseCode() != 200) {

}
```

What is the best way to use connection request to working on local server and hosting server...

Comment: How fast do you expect people to answer your questions?  Specifically in your case it looks like you should look at the server log and URL specifically also check the port the webserver is deployed to. 411 is a server error.